# DateTime Format not being recognized

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a date that I need to get into a `DateTime` object. In my code below I set the `filedate` to the date string that I get and then try two different formats (`patern` and `patern2`. It does not recognize the format and always falls down to the else block and I dont get the datetime object as I need it. I got the format string set up using the specifiers I found on MSDN on [this page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
string filedate = "Tue Aug 12 16:01:29 CDT 2014";
string patern = "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss CDT yyyy";
string patern2 = "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss CDT yyyy";
DateTime dat;
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string outString = "";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(filedate, patern, enUS, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dat))
{
    outString = (dat.ToShortDateString() + " " + dat.ToShortTimeString());
}
else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(filedate, patern2, enUS, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dat))
{
    outString = (dat.ToShortDateString() + " " + dat.ToShortTimeString());
}
else
{
    outString = filedate.Trim(); //always falling to here
}
```

Comment: use HH instead of hh.  HH specifies 24-hour format, hh specifies 12-hour format.

Comment: @cahinton that was part of what i had wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems:

- Your two pattern straings are identical - why try them both?
- `hh` means hour of 12-hour clock; 16 isn't a valid value
- You should escape the `CDT` part as you want it as a literal

I suspect you want:

```
"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'CDT' yyyy";
```

Additionally, if this is always in English, you probably want to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Finally, I suspect this is only going to be valid in the summer... in winter I'm guessing you'll have `CST` instead. Unfortunately this is a horrible format... you may well want to use string operations to strip out the CST/CDT (or whatever it is - will it always be central time?) before parsing. As far as I'm aware, there's no support for parsing those.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I was just doing one pattern but the second was to play with different options. Looks like the HH and escaping the cdt. It should always be a cdt but I am planning on working through handling those next, should be able to handle that with string operations.